# Replacing multiple string values in a column with numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scikit-learn

I am currently working on a data frame in pandas named `df`. One column contains
multiple labels (more than 100, to be exact).

I know how to replace values when there are a smaller amount of values.

For instance, in the typical Titanic example:

```
titanic.Sex.replace({'male': 0,'female': 1}, inplace=True)
```

Of course, doing so for 100+ values would be extremely time-consuming. I have seen similar questions, but all answers involve typing the data. Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': list('ABCDEBJZACA')})
df['factor'] = df['col'].factorize()[0]
```

output:

```
   col  factor
0    A       0
1    B       1
2    D       2
3    C       3
4    E       4
5    B       1
6    J       5
7    Z       6
8    A       0
9    C       3
10   A       0
```

Comment: Although I have gotten an error, it worked. Thank you! See the error below: 

<ipython-input-48-5d0ec988b81e>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @corvusMidnight what was your error?